# Overflow Error while inserting data in Access

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

```
protected void regsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\\Study\\Websites\\2\\database\\shoplocal.accdb");
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into Registration values('" + txtfname.Text + "','" + txtemail.Text + "','" + txtpwd.Text + "','" + txtcnfpwd.Text + "','" + txtcntno.Text + "','" + txtaddrs.Text + "'," + Convert.ToInt32(txtpstlcode.Text) + ")", con);
    int chk = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (chk != 0)
    {

        lblmsg.Text = "Registration Successful";

    }

    //OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("delete * from Inward where Serial_no=" + tb_SLSserial_no.Text + "", con);
    //int chk1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

I am getting an **OleDb Overflow** exception on **int chk = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();**
whenever I click on submit button. Please help.

Comment: Table structure etc might be helpful here, suggests to me that the number of columns you are trying to add doesn't match the number required

Comment: Are you sure? Looks like you just insert one row. What is your table looks like? What is the value of `txtpstlcode.Text` exactly? And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Are you sure that's where you're getting the error? I don't think ExecuteNonQuery throws Overflows. Convert.ToInt32 on the previous line might. What value is txtpstlcode.Text? Is it something which will cause an Int32 to overflow?

Comment: The exception is likely not a StackOverflow exception, but rather a SQL Overflow exception because one of OPs datatypes is too small for their data. It'd be fantastic if OP could actually post the *actual* error and stack trace.

Comment: I hadn't considered a StackOverflow... I just assumed that the convert might overflow. Just goes to show how useful it is if people post the actual error rather than _helpfully_ summarising away all the details.